# QWebView not loading external javascript?

Tags: javascript, qt, qtwebkit, qwebview

It is possible to load an external javascript file from the html using QWebView?

In the following QtProject (all files in the same directory) there is javascript code directly inside the html and also in an external file. I'm missing the external behavior while loading it in QWebView (in the browser it works fine):

MyApp.pro

```
QT       += core gui webkitwidgets

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = MyApp
TEMPLATE = app
DESTDIR = ./

SOURCES += main.cpp

HEADERS  +=
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWebKitWidgets>
#include <QFile>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWebView *view = new QWebView;
    view->show();

    QFile file("qt.html");

    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return -1;

    QString html = QTextStream(&file).readAll();
    view->setHtml(html);

    return a.exec();
}
```

qt.html

```
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="qt.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="hello()">

Test..


<script>
    alert("Hello World INTERNAL!");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

qt.js

```
function hello() {
    alert("Hello World EXTERNAL!");
}
```

Comment: I've never had a problem with this. Are you sure qt.js is in the same folder as your executable?  Or are you using the QRC system?

Comment: Absolutely sure, not using QRC. Did you tried to build my project?

Comment: Oh, you know what? You didn't set the base URL -- look at the 2nd param of QWebView::setHtml().  That needs to be set in order for your application to know where to find that Javascript file.

Comment: Something like `view->setHtml(html, QUrl("C:/Users/User/Downloads/MyApp/"));` is expected to work? It didn't work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively 1:

It seems the javascript isn't evaluated from the html. In other words, the following has no effect:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="qt.js">
</script>
```

It must be done explicitly:

```
QString js = readFile("qt.js");
view->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript(js);
```

And, there is no need to set `baseUrl` in `setHtml()`.

Alternatively 2:

Use the QRC System and set the `baseUrl` in `setHtml`. This way doesn't require a call to `view->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript();`

```
//    QString js = readFile(":/qt.js");
//    view->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript(js);

    QString html = readFile(":/qt.html");
    view->setHtml(html, QUrl("qrc:/"));
```

application.qrc

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
<qresource>
    <file alias="qt.png">resource/qt.png</file>
    <file alias="image.html">resource/image.html</file>
    <file alias="qt.html">resource/qt.html</file>
    <file alias="qt.js">resource/qt.js</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can.
You just need to add file:// at the begining of your src.

```
file:///home/js/somejs.js
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load a local html file, first you need to change the src attribute of the javascript, for example:

then src is changed to src="'file:///D:/home/myWeb/js/myjs.js'"

this will work.
Relative path can also be given.