# QWebEngineView: href in html file not working

Tags: python, pyside2, qwebengineview, qwebenginepage

I have a test.html file like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <a style="padding-right:5px" target="_blank" href="data/">Datadir</a>
</body>
</html>
```

the directory include test.html is like:

```
test.html
data\
    a.txt
    b.txt
```

and I use "file:///remote/us01home19/ktc/public_html/testLocalHref/test.html" and click on Datadir in firefox and chrome, the result is like:

[image]

and:

[image]

I write a pyside2 code to do the same thing, the code is like:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

import os
import sys

class CustomWebEnginePage(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage):
    # Store second window.
    external_window = None

    def acceptNavigationRequest(self, url,  _type, isMainFrame):
        print(url, _type, isMainFrame)
        if _type == QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage.NavigationTypeLinkClicked:
            if not self.external_window:
                self.external_window = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()

            self.external_window.setUrl(url)
            self.external_window.show()
            return False

        return super().acceptNavigationRequest(url,  _type, isMainFrame)
    
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.browser = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setPage(CustomWebEnginePage(self))
        # self.browser.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl("https://code.visualstudio.com"))
        self.browser.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl("file:///remote/us01home19/ktc/public_html/testLocalHref/test.html"))
        # self.browser.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl("file:///remote/tw_rnd1/ktc/prog/python/pyside2/WebEngine/data/aaa.ava.summary.html"))
        #self.browser.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl("file:///remote/tw_rnd1/ktc/prog/python/pyside2/WebEngine/data/aaa_ava_corners/C_1"))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But execute the code, I get the result like:

[image]

but click on the Datadir, there is no response, even QWebEnginePage.acceptNavigationRequest is not triggered. Is there a way to make the QWebEngine behavior like Firefox and Chrome?

I have try to add print message in QWebEnginePage.acceptNavigationRequest function to catch the click dataDir information, but it seems there is no response for this.

python version:python-3.9.0,
os version : "CentOS Linux 7",
Qt Version : "Qt_5.15"
python and Qt are custom build

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QWebView not loading external javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34184704/qwebview-not-loading-external-javascript)

Comment: I think it's not, I have a complicated html that use javascript and it's ok to generate the result I want. But it also have the same problem that if we have  a simple syntax like href="data", it will not work in QWebEngineView, but work on Firefox and Chrome. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to use `data/` instead of `data`? Note that the "complicated html..." aspect is irrelevant to the question, since we can only work with the given code. It will also help to know more about your environment (OS, PySide and Qt versions, and if you're using a custom build).

Comment: Thanks, I try to change it into **data/** but it still not working, I use python-3.9.0, "CentOS Linux 7", "Qt_5.15"

Comment: Please add relevant information to your post ([edit]), not in comments. Also, provide *all* relevant information requested (is it a custom build or not?).

Comment: You said that you use a custom built Qt. Why? What are the differences from the default? For instance, according to the docs, QWebEngineSettings automatically enables `LocalContentCanAccessFileUrls`. Is that attribute set in your build?

Comment: I am not sure what setting has changed, That build by my company IT team. but I have used "self.browser.page().settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.LocalContentCanAccessFileUrls, True)" or False to do test, it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem comes from html **target="_blank"** not work in **QWebEnginePage**, it can avoid by implementing class function **createWindow** in **QtWebEngineWidgets** like:

```
class CustomWebEnginePage(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage):
# Store second window.
external_window = None

def acceptNavigationRequest(self, url,  _type, isMainFrame):
    print(url, _type, isMainFrame)
    if _type == QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage.NavigationTypeLinkClicked:
        if not self.external_window:
            self.external_window = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()

        self.external_window.setUrl(url)
        self.external_window.show()
        return False

    return super().acceptNavigationRequest(url,  _type, isMainFrame)
def createWindow(self, t):
    return self
```

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I overlooked the `_blank` target. That already has lots of answers here on SO: [Window does not open new window or tab on external url link click](//stackoverflow.com/q/55472415) [QWebengine open createwindow if target _blank](//stackoverflow.com/q/47897467) [How to open hyperlink with target="_blank" in PyQtWebEngine?](//stackoverflow.com/q/66350233). Since there are already so many duplicates, and your post may also be misleading due to its URL nature, I suggest you to delete it at once. Still, please consider all suggestions given above for future reference.